# Why does scatterPlotGraph appear as the mirror of actual graph when using customized frame?

Tags: core-plot, scatter-plot

## Heading

I am using CorePlot Library for drawing scatterPlot graph. When i use customized frame for creating CPTXYGraph and CPTGraphHostingView instance, graph appears as the mirrror image of the actual  graph (i.e. in reverted way). Can anyone tell me , whre i am doing mistake.
  Please Help.  Here is my code :

```
graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300)];
CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme];
[graph applyTheme:theme];
CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300)];

[self.view addSubview:hostingView];

hostingView.collapsesLayers = NO; 
hostingView.hostedGraph = graph;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Core Plot code looks fine. Make sure `self.view` doesn't have any transform and/or subview transform applied that might be flipping the graph.

Comment: Thanks Skroch! Actually, when I flip self.view vertically, it appears fine, but, nowhere, I have applied transform and/or subview transform . Anyway, my problem is solved, but can u tell me any other possible reason.